# CHOICE /c wasd /n /t 0.5

Tags: batch-file, batch-choice

I have tried to use the `choice /c adqps /n /t 0.5 /d s` command in a batch file, but cannot find any way to test for user input for less than a second.

I have not been able to find an answer anywhere on the internet. (Even page 10 of Google search)

If someone can show me a way to use the `choice /t` command for less than a second or show me a substitute command that also detects user input, I would be grateful.

Comment: @Ken White OK, thank you for trying though.

Comment: Why you need such a short timeout? Do you want to write a game or similar? Then you better look at other batch concepts like in [dostips: Snake game](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4741) This uses an input thread in batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using choice /? or help choice from a command prompt says that the /t parameter is the number of seconds, and that allowable values are from 0 to 9999. There's no indication that it uses partial seconds, or there would probably be an option to use milliseconds instead of whole seconds or the upper limit would be 9999.99.

Here's the relevant text from the [Choice documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732504%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> /t
>
> Specifies the number of seconds to pause before using the default
>   choice specified by /d. Acceptable values are from 0 to 9999. If /t is
>   set to 0, choice does not pause before returning the default choice.

So the answer is that this can't be done (using Choice, at least), because fractions of a second are not supported.